# Pass data from selected data grid view to another data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rows, indexoutofrangeexception

Hi I'm trying to add a selected datagridview row to another datagridview.

I'm using man object class. Here's my class.

```
 class Man
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {

        set { _name = value; }
        get { return _name; }

    }

    private string _address;
    public string address
    {
        set { _address = value; }
        get { return _address; }

    }
}
```

and I have two Lists here are those.

```
    List<Man> people= new List<Man>();
    List<Man> people2 = new List<Man>();
    public string tempname;
```

Here's whole code for the row click event.

```
    private void dataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            Man manobj = new Man();

            manobj.name = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
            tempname = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
            manobj.address= Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);

            //Adding the man object
            people2.Add(manobj);
            BindingSource manbind2= new BindingSource();
            manbind2.DataSource = people2;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = manbind2;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);

            for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
            {
                Man tempman = people[i] as Man;
                if (tempman.name == tempname)
                {
                    people.Remove(tempman);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

When I click sometimes I get this error message.

> The following exception occured in the DataGridView.
>
> System.indexOutOfRangeException:Index 0 does not have a value at
>   System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32index)at
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32rowIndex)
>   To Replace this default dialog please handle the data error event.

**and cells getting emptied one by one and all the time error message pops up. Can anyone tell me how to correct it?**

Comment: You're trying to add a row to a data grid view that doesn't have rows yet. Basically you're saying row(0) = x, when row(0) isn't initialized yet. Add all the rows to a datatable then set that as your datasource at the very end.

Comment: You can also get more information about your error by going to your data error event in your datagridview, and adding some code. Such as msgbox(e.sender) and etc. This will give you more info on what exactly is giving the error.